# How to Print Array in Label?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to print my Array into my label but I don't found any way to do that.

Here is my array.

```
var lapTime: [[Double]] = [[]]
```

And there is where I put something of cool in my label

```
let str = NSString(format: "%.2f", rows[indexPath.row]["time"]! as! Double)
let arr = ??? // Here I Want to put my array
cell?.textLabel?.text = "\(indexPath.row + 1) -> \(str) -> \(arr)"
```

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assumed your `lapTime` is like below,

```
 let lapTime: [[Double]] = [[33.34,22.876,34.0]]
```

**Method 1:**

```
let arr = lapTime[0].map { (double) -> String in
    return String(double)
}.joined()

self.label.text = arr
```

or

```
let arr = lapTime[0].map { (double) -> String in
            return String(double)
            }.joined(separator: ", ")

self.label.text = arr
```

**Method 2:**

```
for time in lapTime[0]{
    let arr  = (self.label.text ?? "")+" "+String(time) //+"<space>"+ to +","+ if you need lap times are comma separated. 
    self.label.text = arr
}
```

**Note:**

The `lapTime == [[33.34,22.876,34.0],[33.34,22.876,34.0]]`and you had a `UITableView`, then replace `lapTime[0]` to `lapTime[indexPath.row]`.

let me know is that you need.

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: That's it ! Thank you men :)

Comment: One of the best way to use map 

Answer (score 6):

In swift 4.1 and Xcode 9.4.1

My array is like this....

```
array = ["BELT", "BUNKER", "CABLES/ACCESSORIES ", "CABLE", "CHUTES", "GOLD"]
lbl.text = array.joined(separator: ",")
```

Output is :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
let arr = lapTime.map(String.init).joined()
cell?.textLabel?.text = "\(indexPath.row + 1) -> \(str) -> \(arr)"
```

Answer (score -4):

You can easily concat IEnumerables and arrays with string.Join:

```
lblAnswer3.Text = string.Join(", ", number);
```

Comment: Not in Swift rohit!